# Loop with simple dom, just one result

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I tried to parse a website with simple dom but I have only one result.

Below you have two functions, one display only price and work fine.

The second must display some elements like title, price, special but I have just one result.

What's is the problem in my tag ?

Thank you

```
  $url = 'https://www.cdiscount.com/search/10/samsung+galaxy+s7.html#_his_';
  $argument = 'div.prdtPrSt';


  function extractAllPrice($url, $argument) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 10.10; labnol;) ctrlq.org");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    if (is_null($html) || $html === false) {
      $html = file_get_contents($url);

      if (is_null($html)) {
        print_r('error no content');
        return false;
      }
    }

    $content = str_get_html($html);

    foreach($content->find($argument) as $price) {
      preg_match_all('!\d+!', $price, $matches);
      $price_extracted =  (float)implode('.', $matches[0]);
      $result[] = $price_extracted;
    }

    return $result;
  }

  var_dump(extractAllPrice($url, $argument));
```

result

```
array (size=15)
  0 => float 527.4
  1 => float 437.94
  2 => float 637.95
  3 => float 487.54
  4 => float 589
  5 => float 527.4
  6 => float 437.94
  7 => float 487.54
  8 => float 637.95
  9 => float 555
  10 => float 500
  11 => float 714.25
  12 => float 350.9
  13 => float 770.26
  14 => float 589
```

The second function

```
  $url = 'https://www.cdiscount.com/search/10/samsung+galaxy+s7.html#_his_';
  $argument_content = 'div.lpTopTDG';
  $argument_title = 'div.prdtBTit';
  $argument_special_price = 'span.price';
  $argument_price = 'div.prdtPrSt';

  function extractAllPriceTest($url, $argument_content = null, $argument_title= null, $argument_special_price = null, $argument_price = null) {
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 10.10; labnol;) ctrlq.org");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $html = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $error = false;

    if (is_null($html) || $html === false) {
      $html = file_get_contents($url);
      $error = false;

      if (is_null($html)) {
        print_r('error no content');
        $error = true;
        return false;
      }
    }

    $content = str_get_html($html);



    foreach($content->find($argument_content) as $article) {


      $item['title'] = $article->find($argument_title, 0)->plaintext;
      $item['special_price'] = $article->find($argument_special_price, 0)->plaintext;
      $item['normal_price'] = $article->find($argument_price, 0)->plaintext;

      preg_match_all('!\d+!', $item['special_price'], $matches);
      $item['special_price'] =  (float)implode('.', $matches[0]);

      preg_match_all('!\d+!', $item['normal_price'], $matches);
      $item['normal_price'] =  (float)implode('.', $matches[0]);

      $result[] = $item;
    }

    return $result;
  }

  var_dump(extractAllPriceTest($url, $argument_content, $argument_title, $argument_special_price, $argument_price));
```

result

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'title' => string 'Samsung Galaxy S7 Noir' (length=22)
      'special_price' => float 419
      'normal_price' => float 527.4
```